# Launch Console with main class java file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, console

I am having a question that i am having a java project in Eclipse.
main class is in Launcher.java

When i create runnable jar file and run it then it is not running because it needs a console.

I dont want to run my program from Command Prompt or Terminal or Batch file.

I just want to implement a console class in my program which runs my Launcher.java

i.e. when i run my main class in Launcher.java it should run in console.

I once have the code but lost it.

Please help as i am not getting any help from previous topics on StackOverflow.

Comment: Does your manifest file contain main-class entry? If yes, you should be able to run it on double click.

Comment: yes manifest file contain main class entry. When i double click my jar file then it runs but does not open console. My application only works in console, so i need to implement a console inside my project. But i dont know how to do it. I once did but lost the code.